# How to use pypy with python existing calculation code?

Tags: python, numpy

I am little bit new to python and I have a large code base written in python 3.3.2 (32 bit). It uses numpy 1.7.1 and takes a very long time to run because of computationally intensive calculations.

I need to parallelize the code to increase the performance. I am thinking about using `pypy` to parallelize but am unsure how to use it with existing code.

I have search Google but couldn't find and appropriate or satisfactory answer. I also read about using cython but I am unsure how to use that as well.

Could anyone provide pointers on increasing the performance of my code?

Comment: Check this out before you consider immigrating codes from existing python to pypy.http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html

Comment: I've reworded your question to make it more likely to get answers - the question you posted was a bit of a ramble of words. I see this is your first question here, try to format you questions with clear easy to answer points.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Python, I highly recommend taking the time to survey all of the possibilities before jumping into something `pypy` which may not be appropriate for your needs. There are lots of ways to speed up NumPy code, and the best way really depends on exactly what you're doing.

A great starting off point is [Ian Oszvald's High Performance Python tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw9-GckD-gQ). Don't just watch it: follow along and try out the examples!

From there, you should think about whether parallelization will help. There are several options for parallelization, like the stdlib's [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), but a lot of people in the scientific space are using IPython's parallelization capabilities. For learning about this, check out Min Ragan-Kelley's IPython Parallel tutorial ([pt 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4hgalfhc1Y), [pt 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9ijnHPCYhY), [pt 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5mhpKkIx2Y)).

Once you have some sense of what Python is capable of, pick a method for speeding up your code and try it out. When you run into more specific problems, StackOverflow will be able to provide more concrete answers than just some links to tutorials ;)

Comment: I did multiprocessing but it doesn't give effective result.. so how can I use pypy for my existing python code?